# Fedora Video Driver Problem

Tags: drivers, fedora, nvidia-geforce

I have Fedora 14 installed on my laptop with an nvidia 8400M GT card. I installed the kmod-nvidia drivers, however, I could not adjust my screen brightness with via my keyboard, so I decided to uninstall. Now my boot screen is the legacy-like black screen with a blue bar at the bottom and my resolution has changed and I still can not change my screen brightness. I am guessing I either uninstall a package or some file was overwritten. What is the name of the default graphics driver package in Fedora 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the name of the default graphics driver package in Fedora 14?

The open source driver's name is `nv`